# ruby task using 100% of CPU - macbook running

Tags: ruby, macos, puma

When running a rails server or even console. I have a ruby process that will take 100% of the CPU up and cause the laptop to run the fans at full blast. I can stop the task with

```
> spring stop
```

but this isn't a long term solution.

Any ideas if there is a fix/configuration that needs to be made to fix this?

Answer (score 12):

Found a solution to this issue. Apparently the issue resides with the 'listen' gem that's incompatible with MacOs big sur. Updating the gem to this version fixes the issue.

gem 'listen', '>=3.0.5', '<4.0'

Problem and resolution from this thread

https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/636#issuecomment-755404716